# How can I parse a datetime with a nonstandard format (yyyyMMdd:Hmm)?

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, formatting, cultureinfo

We have an integration partner who insists on sending us datetimes as strings in the format `yyyyMMdd:Hmm`, e.g., "20211029:102". Note that the hour does not have a leading zero.

I tried to parse it like this:

```
Datetime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(
   "20211029:102", 
   "yyyyMMdd:hmm", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   DateTimeStyles.None
);
```

But this results in

> FormatException••• String '20211029:102' was not recognized as a valid
> DateTime.

I can make it work by re-adding the missing zero, something like:

```
string datetimeParts = "20211029:102".Split(":");
string value = datetimeParts[0] + datetimeParts[1].PadLeft(4, '0');
Datetime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
    value, 
    "yyyyMMddHHmm", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None
);
```

But I feel I shouldn't need to "preparse" the value. Is it possible to parse this format without pre-processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the time part of your format string, so my answer will explain why you cannot parse `102` with the format string `Hmm`. *(I know you wrote `hmm`, but since you don't have an AM/PM designator, I'll assume that you meant to write `Hmm` instead. The same reasoning applies to `hmm`.)*

If we look at the [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,3517), we can see that the DateTime parser is "greedy": If the [parser encounters a single-letter format specifier (such as `H`)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,3642), it will [still try to consume 2 digits, if two digits are available](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,2889).

In your case, two digits **are** available, so `H` will consume `10` of `102`. This only leaves `2` for the minute, which won't match `mm` (since it only has one digit).

Given this limitation, it's not possible to parse a DateTime value formatted as `Hmm` with `DateTime.ParseExact`. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0) notes the following:

> **Note**
>
> If `format` is a custom format pattern that does not include date or time separators (such as "yyyyMMddHHmm"), use the invariant culture for the `provider` parameter and the widest form of each custom format specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the format pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H".

Comment: Cheers for the great answer on why "yyyyMMdd:Hmm" and "yyyyMMdd:hmm" can't work.  :-)   So that only leaves the question whether there are any alternatives to Datetime.ParseExact which could accept the "H"?  But given the gist of the feedback, it seems doubtful anyone would want to....

Comment: @BrianKessler: I doubt that there is an alternative, and since you have a readable, working solution, I doubt that putting further effort into finding an alternative is worthwhile.

Comment: @BrianKessler: As a side note: Regular expressions *do* support backtracking, so something like `(?<hour>[0-9]?[0-9])(?<minute>[0-9][0-9])` should work. But that won't be shorter than your current solution either.